# How to change a KivyMD Menu caller to a Widget in a ScreenManager Screen

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy, kivymd

So, I'm working on a simple kivy app and I have three buttons ([`MDRaisedButton's`](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/index.html#mdraisedbutton)) which each open the same KivyMD Menu ([`MDDropdownMenu`](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/menu/index.html)) on release.

1. Two of these buttons are in different [`ScreenManager`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) screens.
2. The other button is in a [`GridLayout`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html) in the `Screen` outside
   the `ScreenManager`.

When I open the menu using the buttons inside of the `ScreenManager`, **the menu appears at the button that is outside of the `ScreenManager`, no matter which button I press.**

---

So how can I change the caller, or the position of the menu when it appears to be that of the buttons in my `ScreenManager` screens?

---

Me clicking on the button inside the `ScreenManager` screen:
[image]

The menu appears on the wrong button:
[image]

---

**Code:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

Screens = ["First", "Second"]

KV = '''
Screen:
    screen_man:screen_man
    button_outside:button_outside
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        cols: 1
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: button_outside
            text: "Outside Screen Manager"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .9}
            on_release: app.threeD_menu.open()

        ScreenManager:
            id:screen_man
            FirstScreen:
            SecondScreen:


<FirstScreen>:
    name:"First"
    screen_man1:screen_man1

    MDRaisedButton:
        id: screen_man1
        text: "Inside Screen Manager1"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        on_release: app.threeD_menu.open()
    
    MDLabel:
        text: "Screen Manager1"
        font_size: "40dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": 0.9}

<SecondScreen>:
    name:"Second"
    screen_man2:screen_man2
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: screen_man2
        text: "Inside Screen Manager2"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": .5}
        on_release: app.threeD_menu.open()
    
    MDLabel:
        text: "Screen Manager2"
        font_size: "40dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": 0.9}

'''


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ExampleApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = 'Example'
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        threeD_items = [
            {
                "text": f"{i}",
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "on_release": lambda x=f"{i}": self.threeD_refresh(x),
            } for i in Screens
        ]

        self.threeD_menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.button_outside,
            items=threeD_items,
            width_mult=4,
        )

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(self.screen)
        return sm

    def threeD_refresh(self, operation):
        self.threeD_menu.dismiss()
        self.screen.screen_man.current = operation


ExampleApp().run()
```

Can someone please help with this? I've searched the [docs](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/menu/index.html) and Google and found nothing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following line in your code for the MDRaisedButton on_release event handler.

```
on_release: app.threeD_menu.open()
```

The menu has no idea who opened it. The key here is to pass a **caller** to whatever function opens the menu, so the MDDropdownMenu has that context of who called it.

Define a new function called **launch_menu** with the following code:

```
def launch_menu(self, my_caller):
    self.threeD_menu.caller=my_caller
    self.threeD_menu.open()
```

Then, change the event handlers to call this function, rather than just the menu open function:

```
MDRaisedButton:
    id: button_outside
    text: "Outside Screen Manager"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .9}
    on_release: app.launch_menu(self)
```

Now, when your eventhandler is called, it passes to the menu object who called it, and the menu object can launch from there.

[image]

Full code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

Screens = ["First", "Second"]

KV = '''
Screen:
    screen_man:screen_man
    button_outside:button_outside
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        cols: 1
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: button_outside
            text: "Outside Screen Manager"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .9}
            on_release: app.launch_menu(self)

        ScreenManager:
            id:screen_man
            FirstScreen:
            SecondScreen:


<FirstScreen>:
    name:"First"
    id:"first_screen"
    screen_man1:screen_man1

    MDRaisedButton:
        id: screen_man1
        text: "Inside Screen Manager1"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        on_release: app.launch_menu(self)
    
    MDLabel:
        text: "Screen Manager1"
        font_size: "40dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": 0.9}

<SecondScreen>:
    name:"Second"
    screen_man2:screen_man2
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: screen_man2
        text: "Inside Screen Manager2"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": .5}
        on_release: app.launch_menu(self)
    
    MDLabel:
        text: "Screen Manager2"
        font_size: "40dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": 0.9}

'''


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ExampleApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = 'Example'
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        threeD_items = [
            {
                "text": f"{i}",
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "on_release": lambda x=f"{i}": self.threeD_refresh(x),
            } for i in Screens
        ]

        self.threeD_menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.button_outside,
            items=threeD_items,
            width_mult=4,
        )
        

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(self.screen)
        return sm

    def threeD_refresh(self, operation):
        self.threeD_menu.dismiss()
        self.screen.screen_man.current = operation
    
    def launch_menu(self, my_caller):
        self.threeD_menu.caller=my_caller
        self.threeD_menu.open()
        


ExampleApp().run()
```